Application not rendering private routes
This are the routes in my App.jsx:
I added the /* after I received You rendered descendant  (or called useRoutes()) at "/home" (under ) but the parent route path has no trailing "*". This means if you navigate deeper, the parent won't match anymore and therefore the child routes will never render.
Please change the parent  to .
<Routes>
  <Route path="/*" element={<LoginPage />} />
  <Route path="/register" element={<RegisterPage />} />
  <Route path="/profile/*" element={<CustomRoute nav={"/home"} path={"/profile"} role={["JobSeeker", "Employer", "Admin"]} element={<ProfilePage />} />} />
  <Route path="/home/*" element={<CustomRoute nav={"/"} path={"/home"} role={["JobSeeker", "Employer", "Admin"]} element={<Homepage />} />} />
  <Route path="/matches/*" element={<CustomRoute nav={"/home/*"} path={"/matches"} role={["JobSeeker", "Employer"]} element={<MatchesPage />} />} />
  <Route path="/employer/*" element={<CustomRoute nav={"/home"} path={"/employer"} role={["Employer"]} element={<EmployerPage />} />} />
  <Route path="/about/*" element={<CustomRoute nav={"/home"} path={"/about"} role={["JobSeeker", "Employer", "Admin"]} element={<AboutPage />} />} />
  <Route path="/contact/*" element={<CustomRoute nav={"/home"} path={"/contact"} role={["JobSeeker", "Employer"]} element={<ContactPage />} />} />
  <Route path="/support/*" element={<CustomRoute nav={"/home"} path={"/support"} role={["JobSeeker", "Employer"]} element={<SupportPage />} />} />
  <Route path="*" element={<ErrorPage />} />
</Routes>

And this is my CustomRoute:
import React from "react";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { Route, Navigate, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import { getUserRole } from "../../utils/getUserRole";

const CustomRoute = ({ nav, role, ...props}) => {
  const user = useSelector((state) => state.users);
  const isAuthenticated = user.isAuthenticated;
  const userRole = getUserRole(user);

  if (isAuthenticated && role.includes(userRole)) {
    return (
      <Routes>
        <Route {...props}  />
      </Routes>
    );
  } else if (!isAuthenticated) {
    return <Navigate to={"/"} />;
  } else {
    return <Navigate to={nav} />;
  }
};

export default CustomRoute;


For some reason now I don't receive any warning anymore but my page isn't rendered at all.
Thanks!
I tried to add /* to the parent routes in App.jsx - it made the warning disappear but the page is not rendered anymore.
It worked before when I used 1 role for each route component - could it be something related to this?
